# Small Floating Cabinet on Drywall?

Tags: drywall

I want to install this square floating cabinet on my walls, but it's small, so I will only be able to hit one stud with it. If I add a wall anchor to the other side, will it be strong enough? Or will the cabinet will just fall?? What should I do then?
Thanks, I tried looking for an answer but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: you can attach to the stud in two places, at the top and the bottom of the cabinet.  ... that should keep it on the wall and also prevent it from spinning around one mounting screw ... use a drywall anchor to keep the loose end from pulling away from the wall.

Comment: 1: Show the size of the cabinet in dimensions. 2 What is the weight of the cabinet and also a good estimate on the weight of the items you will store in the cabinet. Where will the stud be - in the middle the right side , left side of the cabinet ? Post a picture too that would be helpful.
This information will help us to know if you should do it and with what anchors you should use and how many to use in order to be sure it is safely installed.

Comment: @jsotola You should submit this as answer. I would upvote.

Comment: @Ken, this user probably doesn't have repuation to post a pic. But agreed dimensions and expected weight is important. A cabinet full of books or dinner plates is not the same as one holding a few knick knacks.

Comment: @Stanwood you gathered my point well - and small cabinet to one might be a 12W x 6D  x 12H to another it might be 12W x 16D x 36H solid oak which is a lot heavier just by itself - let alone if there are books vs figurines. Op can post via this web and just link to it : https://imgur.com/

Answer (score -1):

Hang a piece of 1/2" to 3/4" birch plywood (depending on how strong you need it to be), the same dimensions as the cabinet, on the wall, securing it with counter sunk #10 or larger screws, at the stud, and countersunk toggles at the corners.

Hang your cabinet from the plywood, and stain/paint the plywood to match.

If you don't want to see the plywood grain, you can cut it a little narrow, and glue hardwood edge banding to it, and then stain/paint to match.